# JRebel cache on Docker

Tags: caching, docker, jrebel

I have using Docker to deploy app using JRebel. My question is: where I can find this directory?

**/home/exion/.jrebel/cache**

Comment: The path should exist inside the docker container filesystem. However why exactly are you looking for this path? Only classes sent there via JRebel IDE plugin will be reloaded as licensing check is done in that transaction.

Comment: I am trying to delete JRebel cache. I suspect that cache could cause problem with loading beans which throws javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JMS_QCF exception.